# Analog output doesn't work for just 2 LEDs [Arduino Mega]

Tags: arduino-mega, pins, potentiometer, analogwrite

I am having a problem with an Arduino Mega 2560.

Everything works fine, the ultrasonic sensors work fine, and the other LEDs work fine. Although there is 2 LEDs who do not work right and when I do `analogWrite()`, they actually do `digitalWrite()`. I have tried to attach these two LEDs to a potentiometer (potentiometer works fine, values are tested) but it always does `digitalWrite()` not `analogWrite()`.

I have tested the LEDs and potentiometer on an Arduino Uno in PWM pins and analog pin and yes it does work very well.

Please mind that these LEDs are attached to analog pins. Why is this? Because I do not have anymore PWM pins available to use and so I have to use analog pins. No way I can rearrange this.

Here is part of the code (only part otherwise it's too long, most of my pins are taken):

```cpp
//Leds//

int led = A4;
int ledUV = A3;

//Potentiometer//

int potReading;
int potPin = A2;
int lightDim;


void setup(){

    Serial.begin(9600);

    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledUV, OUTPUT);

    pinMode(potPin, INPUT);


}

void loop(){

    potReading = analogRead(potPin);
    lightDim = (255./1023.)*potReading;

    analogWrite(led, lightDim);
//  analogWrite(ledUV, lightDim);
//  Serial.println("pot: ");
//  Serial.println(potReading);
//  Serial.println(" ");
    Serial.println("dim: ");
    Serial.println(lightDim);
//  analogWrite(led, 255);
//  analogWrite(ledUV, 255);

}
```

Comment: < Why is this? "this" being what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference: [`analogWrite()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/analogWrite)

The pins 2 - 13 and 44 - 46 are the PWM pins for `analogWrite()`.

That means you have 15 PWM pins. Did you use them all?

You could add a module with more PWM outputs. Search for: Arduino 16 channel PWM

The Arduino Mega does not have analog outputs, only digital PWM outputs.

Comment: Thank you so much man it did work! I did not knew about 44-46!

Answer (score 4):

Analog pins an only *read* analog values, not *write* them.

`analogWrite()` is a deceptive name. It should really be `PWMWrite()` since all it does is PWM. And that, of course, needs PWM pins.

Comment: This is a good answer too, but arduino uno analog pins have anolog output, as this procedure and code worked on a uno.

Comment: No they don't. There is no analog output on any atmega chips. Whatever you did before it certainly wasn't analog output.

Comment: Do you want me to post a video?

Comment: I'd love to see that, yes. As well as the code that is doing it.